# Dual Boot Windows 7 and 10

Tags: multi-boot

I don't see that specific answer in the posts. I just purchased a new computer with Windows 10 installed. My current PC has Windows 7 installed. I would like to simply remove the HDD from my current PC and install it in the new PC so that I can boot to either OS. Do I do that by simply accessing the boot priority on each instance and choosing the one that I want running or can I have the option appear on my screewn at each reboot? Obviously I would prefer the second option.

Comment: Ignoring the original Win10 and dual boot aspect, simply moving the Win7 HDD will probably cause it to fail to boot, as well as probably violate the Win7 license.  Is the Win7 an OEM or full-retail version?

Comment: It is a full retail version.

Comment: Something else to consider. If it's a brand new PC that comes with the latest generation of Intel or AMD processors, these do not support Windows 7. There's also a good chance that you won't be able to find drivers for your new system that will work on Windows 7. Generally taking out a hard drive with an OS installed on it and putting it into another PC doesn't really work too well, and even more so in your case considering you'll have trouble finding drivers that will work on Windows 7.

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is avoiding having to reinstall all my programs onto my new PC. Is there a workaround that anyone can suggest? I am reasonably tech savvy but far from a technician or programmer so the simpler the solution, if there is one, the better.

Comment: I wrote a detailed answer below. Going from Windows 7 to 10, you would be unwise, and likely waste a lot of time, trying to do anything but what I outlined and/or a FULL clean install. You can't do an upgrade like that. You need to fresh install 100%. It's just too big of a change to your system to even think that you will have nothing but headaches. If you can get your OS up and running on your hardware, install all the software again and run a healthy system.

Answer (score -1):

Factoring there are no issues regarding hardware compatibility with your motherboard, chipset, and peripherals, my recommendation is to buy a 5.25 Drive Bay and install it in your computer, likely under your ROM Drive.

The 5.25 Options will accept both spinning and SDD drives.

- Back Up Everything.
- Remove your OS HDD.
- Install the HDD Docking Bay (usually push button and open a slide door to remove the drive).
- Wire the back of the HDD bay SSD using the cable from your OS Sata cable which you removed. Connect the power cables to the bay.
- Insert in your WIN 7 Drive. Boot, make sure it works.
- NOW...
- Remove your SSD WIN 7 OS drive from the bay/dock.
- Replace with a new/formatted SSD for your WIN 10 OS.
- Set BIOS to boot from ROM and do a clean install of WIN 10 to your new SSD.

The only issues you may run into will be hardware compatibility issues. Windows 10 not behaving with the older hardware.

But as long as you don't flash any hardware/firmware, you should be able to simply revert back to your Win 7 by replacing the Win 10 drive in the dock with your original Win 7 drive.

I don't see any issues there in terms of not being able to roll back- provided you don't do any firmware/hardware bios flash updates or what not.

Something Like This From Amazon would Work:  You may want to get a Key model where you need a Key to unlock as it's your OS Drive.

[HDD DUAL SSD SPINNING INTERNAL BAY - AMAZON](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00856XFUS)

Comment: this **will not** work. You need to remove licensing, driver and configuration with [sysprep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation), or it'll likely fail to boot on another PC. Only Windows-to-go has the ability to boot on pretty much any PC

Comment: He said he purchased the OS outright. Nothing prevents a person from upgrading their OS when purchased stand alone.

Comment: 1. A retail Windows is only permitted to be installed on a single machine. To many hardware changes will invalidate the activation immediately. Moving the OS to another PC is a usage term violation. 2. The fact that he bought the license is completely irrelevant to the technical fact that Windows won't boot by simply plugging the disk to another computer. I bet you didn't even try this

Comment: I have multiple boot setups using this method, all with retail license keys, I pay for my software. I have been doing this for years without a single issue. I understanding "Installing a Single OS License" on more than one machine is prohibited, however, removing the OS drive, and using the PARTS for a new build with a new OS drive, with a legitimate license key, using parts you own, which were not bought as a build, I can't see being a violation of the TOS. Are you trying to say I cannot be whimsical? I had windows 7, upgraded, changed my mind, decided try again? Its my hard ware.

Comment: And on top of which, he could simply scrap the computer/parts and make a 2nd build, if he had two hard drives, two purchased OSs, I see no difference, in fact, then he WOULD be running 2 OSs at the same time. This keeps him to running a single instance at any given time and never using the 2nd seat on two machines.  Regardless worse thing that happens is it asks you to validate. And you do. But buying a FULL Windows 10 Key does not invalidate your Windows 7 Key. People move software all the time due to hardware failures. Besides Win7 is EOL and Gates is off saving the world. It's moot

Comment: And what exactly Defines "Moving" an OS. If you own a retail OS, build your own PC, you can certainly move the OS. All at once or very slowly as you upgrade your GPU, your Spinning Drive to an SSD, your Mobo goes bad, you want a better Soundcard... when all is said and done it's not even the same computer.

Comment: Who said that buying a new key invalidates the old one? You're free to use as many licenses as you want. And you're also allowed to change hardware, whether SSD or GPU, but if there are major hardware changes then windows activation will pop up and whether it's possible to reactivate or not depends on the activator. But that's the minor point. What I'm saying is that you need to generalize the installation so that windows will boot properly, because Windows assumes many devices don't change and won't check them again for faster boot. That's why there's the hardware profile feature in Windows